# infix operator precedence in Haskell

Tags: haskell

For the following Haskell expression

> return a >>= f

Should it be read as

> (return a) >>= f

or

> return (a >>= f)?

what are the related rules here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule is always that function application has higher precedence than any operator, so

```
return a >>= f
```

Is parsed as

```
(return a) >>= f
```

no matter what functions or operators are being used instead of `return`, `f`, and `>>=`.

---

That means things like

```
divide :: Int -> Int -> Double
divide x y = (fromIntegral x) / (fromIntegral y)
```

Are equivalent to

```
divide :: Int -> Int -> Double
divide x y = fromIntegral x / fromIntegral y
```

Another example where this is even more useful is in function composition:

```
something :: [Int] -> [Int]
something xs = filter even . map (+1) . zipWith (*) [1..] . take 200 . cycle $ xs
```

As you can see here, we even have `zipWith` taking two arguments composed with several other functions.  This is equivalent to having put parentheses around every component of the composition.

Comment: Thanks. This is a little bit confusing for beginners since in C, 
`return 1+2;`
will return 3.

Comment: @ahala This can be a problem for beginners, and many people think that having `return` at all is a bad idea.  Unfortunately we do for historical reasons, but I would be happy to see it go in the future.  One of the things to remember is that `return` is just a function, it doesn't do anything special, it isn't a keyword or anything, and it won't exit its parent function early.  This is very counter intuitive for people coming from C-style languages.